# Evaluating a statistical model in R

Tags: r, logistic-regression, threshold, precision-recall

I have a very big data set (`ds`). One of its columns is `Popularity`, of type `factor` ('High' / ' Low').

I split the data to 70% and 30% in order to create a training set (`ds_tr`) and a test set (`ds_te`).

I have created the following model using a Logistic regression:

```
mdl <- glm(formula = popularity ~ . -url , family= "binomial", data = ds_tr )
```

then I created a `predict` object (will do it again for `ds_te`)

```
y_hat = predict(mdl, data = ds_tr - url , type = 'response')
```

I want to find the precision value which corresponds to a cutoff threshold of 0.5 and find the recall value which corresponds to a cutoff threshold of 0.5, so I did:

```
library(ROCR)
pred <- prediction(y_hat, ds_tr$popularity)
perf <- performance(pred, "prec", "rec")
```

The result is a table of many values

```
str(perf)

Formal class 'performance' [package "ROCR"] with 6 slots
  ..@ x.name      : chr "Recall"
  ..@ y.name      : chr "Precision"
  ..@ alpha.name  : chr "Cutoff"
  ..@ x.values    :List of 1
  .. ..$ : num [1:27779] 0.00 7.71e-05 7.71e-05 1.54e-04 2.31e-04 ...
  ..@ y.values    :List of 1
  .. ..$ : num [1:27779] NaN 1 0.5 0.667 0.75 ...
  ..@ alpha.values:List of 1
  .. ..$ : num [1:27779] Inf 0.97 0.895 0.89 0.887 ...
```

How do I find the specific precision and recall values corresponding to a cutoff threshold of 0.5?

Comment: Improve the explanation and explain how to obtain the requested value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Acces** the slots of performance object (through the combination of @ + list)

We create a dataset with all possible values:

```
probab.cuts <- data.frame(cut=perf@alpha.values[[1]], prec=perf@y.values[[1]], rec=perf@x.values[[1]])
```

You can view **all** associated values

```
probab.cuts
```

If you want to **select** the requested values, it is trivial to do:

```
tail(probab.cuts[probab.cuts$cut > 0.5,], 1)
```

Manual **check**

```
tab <- table(ds_tr$popularity, y_hat > 0.5)
tab[4]/(tab[4]+tab[2]) # recall
tab[4]/(tab[4]+tab[3]) # precision
```

Comment: Thanks, but i still have a problem when trying to evaluate the model on the test set (ds_te) since y_hat is different in length then ds_te$popularity. any thoughts?

Comment: In fact, it is more correct to assess the model use the test data. So, estimate and use: "y_hat_test <- predict(mdl, data = ds_te - url , type = 'response')" and calculate "pred" and "perf" with the new data. Finally, use the code of this answer with "ds_te$popularity" and the new "y_hat_test" in the table function.